# getting system identification code (SID) in Android

Tags: android

I'd be much obliged for information regarding how can I get the System Identification code of (SID) a phone in android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the SID (5 character string, right?), but [`ServiceState#getOperatorNumeric`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html#getOperatorNumeric()) might be what you're looking for:

> Get current registered operator numeric id In GSM/UMTS, numeric format is 3 digit country
>   code plus 2 or 3 digit network code

Comment: Well , I'm looking for "System Identification Code (SID) - a unique 5-digit number that is assigned to each carrier by the FCC , according to http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cell-phone3.htm" , so this seems right !

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for this number. I use `CdmaCellLocation.getSystemId()`.